# Order and Distinct in the same Query problem rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, activerecord

In rails I have the following method for sorting and filtering students:

```
 def self.get_students(student_ids, sort_by, name, descending, lesson_ids, months, upcoming)
    students = StudentProfile.where(id: student_ids)
    students = students.where(["CONCAT(first_name, ' ', last_name) ILIKE ?", "%#{name}%"]) if name.present?

    if upcoming || months != 0 || sort_by == 'lesson_date'
      students = students.select('student_profiles.*, events.start_time')
                         .joins(student_lesson_participations: { lesson_schedule: :event })
                         .where(lesson_schedules: { id: lesson_ids })
                         .group('student_profiles.id, events.start_time')
                      
    end 

    students = students.where('events.start_time > ?', Time.current) if upcoming
    students = students.where('events.start_time > ?', months.months.ago) if months != 0
    students = if sort_by == 'lesson_date'
                 students.order('events.start_time ASC')
               else
                 students.order(sort_by.to_sym)
                         .distinct
               end

    students = students.reverse_order if descending
    students.includes(:profile_picture_attachment)
  end
```

The StudentLessonParticipation model belongs to StudentProfile and belongs to LessonSchedule so it is used to define a many to many relationship between StudentProfile and LessonSchedule. LessonSchedule also has one event. What I am trying to accomplish when I pass the lesson_date param is to return distinct StudentProfiles ordered by event.start_time, the problem is that when I order by event.start_time I also have to add events.start_time in the group clause otherwise rails will generate an exception telling me I have to do so. Obviously that wouldn't be wise since it will omit the students that participate in the same lesson because of the group by start_time condition. I am stuck here.

I am expecting to get a list of students distinct by id ordered by their lesson date.

Answer (score 0):

What `events.start_time` is it that you think this would order by? The first? The last? All of them? A random one?

What Postgres is kindly trying to tell you is that this is ambiguous and if you want to select or use the value from the joined table you either need to use an aggregate function like `MIN` or `MAX` or add the columns from the join table into the GROUP BY clause so that there is only one unique value per group.

I would start by adding an indirect assocation to remove some of the stink:

```
class StudentProfile < ApplicationRecord
  # ...
  has_many :lesson_schedules, through: :student_lesson_participations
  has_many :events, through: :lesson_schedules
end
```

Then apply an aggregate function to avoid the ambigiouty:

```
# This doesn't cause the issue in the question since events.created_at is 
# used in a aggregate function.
StudentProfile.joins(:events)
              .group(:id)
              .order(Event.arel_table[:created_at].max, :desc)
```

Beyond that your method badly needs re-working. Having seven required positional args that must be passed in order is a recipe for disaster. Use [keywords](https://thoughtbot.com/upcase/videos/ruby-keyword-arguments).

Also consider moving this code out of your StudentProfile model or wherever it lives now and create a separate class that takes a base scope and set of filters as input and creates a filtered ActiveRecord::Relation.  Spread the "filters" out into methods that just do one thing instead of a long ranting proceedure. Remember your cyclic complexity and method length metrics!